# find: do nothing, if no files get specified

Tags: find

I want to call use `find` on some filenames.

```
find $(do_something to find filenames) -print0 | xargs -r0 ls -ld
```

This breaks if `$(do_something to find filenames)` returns nothing: The find-command starts to do recursive search.

Is there a way to tell find to do nothing if it gets no explicit filename/dirname as argument?

Comment: `find` generally **IS** the "something you do to find filenames", that's why it's called `find`.   what is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: What you like to control depends on the `find` implementation. Some `find` implementations complain when there is no path argument, others start with the current directors. BTW: The POSIX standard requires `find` to fail when there is no path argument.

Comment: @schily thank you for getting feedback from you (Jörg). How would you solve this?

Comment: See my new answer - a commend does not allow useful formatting of the text.

Comment: @schily, no, POSIX doesn't require `find` to fail when there is no path argument. It requires applications to invoke `find` with at least one path argument, but leaves the behaviour unspecified with that starts with `-`, `!` or `(` to explicitely allow the behaviour of implementations that don't require a path argument

Comment: Well, it seems that POSIX is self contradicting here. The synopsis mentions at least one path argument and I am sure that the synopsis is part of the normative text.

Comment: @schily The synopsis tells you how you should invoke `find`, not what would happen if you invoked it any other way.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`, I'd do:

```
files=($(do_something to find filenames))
(($#files)) && find $files ...
```

With `tcsh`:

```
set files=(`do_something to find filenames`)
if ($#files) find $files:q ...
```

With `bash`, `mksh` or `ksh93`,

```
set -f; files=($(do_something to find filenames))
((${#files[@]})) && find "${files[@]}" ...
```

POSIXly:

```
set -f; set -- $(do_something to find filenames)
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && find "$@" ...
```

(in bash and other POSIX shells, `$(...)` splits (on `$IFS`: space, tab and newline by default), but also performs globbing on the resulting words which I don't expect you'd want here hence the `set -f`. Other shells ((t)csh, zsh, fish, rc, es...) don't have that problem).

Comment: What you mention to be POSIX dies not work with a POSIX shell.

Comment: Thanks @schily. That copy-paste mistake should now be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

How about doing this:

```
paths=$(do_something to find filenames)
if [ "$paths" ]; then
    find "$paths" ...
fi
```

This works independent from the `find` implementation.

Note that `find "$paths"` with more than a single path name causes problems.
If the path names do not contain spaces, you may use: `find $paths`, otherwise, a working alternative is this function:

```
dofind() {
    set -f
    set -- $(do_something to find filenames)
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
        find "$@" ...
    fi
    set +f
}
```

It disables file globbing and then uses `set --` to set the shells arg vector. This works with any POSIX shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `find` an extra, non-existant directory to start from:

```
find " " $(do_something to find filenames) -print0 | xargs -r0 ls -ld
```

To make this tidy, drop `find`'s error output:

```
find " " $(do_something to find filenames) -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -r0 ls -ld
```

(but then you won't notice if another error occurs...).

When `do_something to find filenames` outputs filenames, `find` will complain about `" "` but will still process the rest of the command line. When no filenames are output, `find` will again complain about `" "` but won't add its default `.`.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh` (and most non-Bourne derived shells), when a (or *all* depending on the shell) *glob* doesn't expand, the command is aborted.

`$(do_something to find filenames)` is not a glob, but you can make it become one by appending a glob qualifier in `zsh`:

```
 find $(do_something to find filenames)(#q) -print0...
```

Above, that `(#q)` (an empty glob qualifier, so does nothing otherwise) is appended to the last word resulting of the splitting of the output of `do_something to find filenames`, so the command will be aborted if that command produces no (or blank) output, but also if that last word (and that last word only) doesn't resolve to an existing path. You can make it apply to every  word resulting of that splitting (so that the command be aborted if any of those words doesn't resolve to an existing file) with:

```
 find ${^$(do_something to find filenames)}(#q) -print0...
```